# How to add a total income based on category

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

**I've data frame like this**

[image]

I want to group and sum the income of my customers according to the cathegory

First: i want to group customer's income according to the month

Second: after customer's income is grouped based on the month, i want to group it based on import or export

Third: i want to group customer's income based on: "charge, interest, and cost"

Forth: i want to add a total customer's income based on "charge, interest, and cost"

**My expected**

[image]

this is my last code

> df = df.groupby ("[information", "Name"] ). Agg("sum)

Im so confused" merge and cell " in python and sum based on category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) which has a lot of flexibility:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  Month   Name      Info   Ex/Im  Income
0   Jan  Alice    charge  export     100
1   Jan  Alice  interest  import      10
2   Jan    Bob      cost  export     200
3   Feb  Alice    charge  export     100
4   Jan    Bob      cost  export     200

In [12]: df.pivot_table(index="Name", columns=["Month", "Ex/Im", "Info"], values="Income", aggfunc='sum')
Out[12]:
Month    Feb    Jan
Ex/Im export export          import
Info  charge charge   cost interest
Name
Alice  100.0  100.0    NaN     10.0
Bob      NaN    NaN  400.0      NaN

In [13]: df.pivot_table(index="Name", columns=["Month", "Ex/Im", "Info"], values="Income", aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[13]:
Month    Feb    Jan
Ex/Im export export        import
Info  charge charge cost interest
Name
Alice    100    100    0       10
Bob        0      0  400        0
```

Comment: @andy_Hanyden can i add column with values from difference dataframe?

Comment: And why i get - 5??